# How to save elements with different class names in separate variables more efficiently?

Tags: javascript, class, variables

In my program I save my elements in each variable in a classic way. But there are many lines of code when there are many elements. Is there a more efficient way to do it?

```
  let el1 = document.getElementsByClassName('class-1');
  let el2 = document.getElementsByClassName('class-2');
  let el3 = document.getElementsByClassName('class-3');
  let el4 = document.getElementsByClassName('class-4');
  let el5 = document.getElementsByClassName('class-5');
  let el6 = document.getElementsByClassName('class-6');
  let el7 = document.getElementsByClassName('class-7');
  let el8 = document.getElementsByClassName('class-8');
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array

Comment: Consider putting the same class on all the elements you want, and then use `getElementsByClassName()` once to obtain a collection of all of those elements

Comment: This is most likely an [*XY-Problem*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) - You should explain what you're building, give a bigger picture, instead of focusing on a wrong approach.

Answer (score 1):

You can have all the classes in an array, then loop through the classes:

```
let classNameArr = ['class-1', 'class-2', 'class-3', 'class-4', 'class-5', 'class-6', 'class-7', 'class-8'];
let elementArr = [];

    
classNameArr.forEach(cn => elementArr.push(document.getElementsByClassName(cn)));
```

Now access them in the following way:

```
let el1 = elementArr[0];
let el2 = elementArr[1];
....
```

Comment: That's a great solution, but it appears you left out the closing parenthesis ')' at the end. It should be like this: `classNameArr.forEach(cn => elementArr.push(document.getElementsByClassName(cn))); `

Comment: :\ Seems like you're (with this odd solution) back on the same bandwagon of uselessly writing lines and lines of `let elN = elementArr[N];` (PS `let`...?)

Answer (score 0):

You can save the elements to an Object, to be able to retrieve them by name (`el1` ... `elx`). This can be done using a [reducer function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) on the array of elements.

Something like:

```js
createDemoElems();

// accumulate the elements with className .class-1 ... class-x
// into myElems
const myElems = [...document.querySelectorAll(`[class^=class-]`)]
  .reduce( (acc, elem) => {
    const elemIndex = [...elem.classList]
      .find(cln => cln.startsWith(`class-`))
      .replace(/[^\d]/g, ``);

    return {...acc, [`el${elemIndex}`]: elem};
  }, {});

// Now you can retrieve an elements using ...
console.log(myElems.el3);

// create 10 elements with class 'class-x'
function createDemoElems() {
  for (let i = 0; i<11; i+=1) {
    document.body.insertAdjacentHTML(`beforeend`,
    `<div class="class-${i + 1} somethingElse">div.class-${i + 1}</div>`);
  }
}
```

Comment: Actually, the correct selector should be `[class^=class-], [class*=" class-"]` . Also I would request from OP an explanation of what he's doing. It all seems like the wrong approach to a missed problem solution premise.